# Polymorphism with 3 classes in C++

Tags: c++

The following code prints 1 2, but I would expect it to print 1 1.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class A {
public:
    virtual void f() { cout << "0" << endl; }
}; 

class B : public A{
public:
    void f() { cout << "1" << endl; }
};

class C : public B{
public:
    void f() { cout << "2" << endl; }
};

int main() {
    A *pa = new B();
    B *pb = new C();
    pa->f();
    pb->f();
}
```

In my understanding, pa->f() executes B's f() function since A's is virtual, but why does pb->f() execute C's f() function when B's f() is not virtual.

Additionally, if I remove 'virtual' from class A, it prints 0 1, which makes sense because A and B execute their own f() functions since they aren't virtual. How come pb->f() changes if it isn't affected since it's only A that changes?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> but why does pb->f() execute C's f() function when B's f() is not virtual.

Because the dynamic type of `pb` is `C` and `C::f` is indeed virtual. When you declare

```
virtual void f();
```

in the base class, every other `void f()` of the derived classes in the hierarchy is also virtual, as per §10.3/2:

> If a virtual member function vf is declared in a class Base and in a class Derived, derived **directly or indirectly** from Base, a member function vf with the same name, parameter-type-list (8.3.5), cv-qualification, and ref- qualifier (or absence of same) as Base::vf is declared, then Derived::vf is also virtual (whether or not it is so declared) and it overrides112 Base::vf.

(emphasis mine)

In fact:

```
class A {
public:
    virtual void f() { cout << "0" << endl; }
}; 

class B : public A{
public:
    virtual void f() { cout << "1" << endl; }
};

class C : public B{
public:
    virtual void f() { cout << "2" << endl; }
};
```

is equivalent to your code. It just so happens that the C++ standard allows `virtual` to be omitted in those cases.

Comment: So when f() in class A is virtual, will it only look for f() in the class lower by 1 level? In other words it'll jump to B's f() but not C's f() although B's f() is also virtual?

Comment: @mzee99, nope. When `f` of class `A` is virtual and you call, let's say, `Z::f` down 20 levels **in the hierarchy**, that function will also be virtual.

Comment: I mean when A is looking for the function to replace its virtual function. Why does A take B's f() when it could take C's f()?

Comment: @mzee99, in the first case you mean? (`pa->f();`)

Comment: @mzee99, because the *dynamic type* of `pa` is `B`, not `C`.

Comment: @mzee99, the dynamic type is the "real" type of the object, that becomes `B*` when you do: `A *pa = new B();`.

Answer (score 2):

It happens because writing virtual keyword in subclasses is not necessary, it just improves readability.